# regular expression for mod rewrite

Tags: regex

im trying to write a regular expression for a mod rewrite rule running on a windows server. so far ive tried

```
RewriteRule ^/hcp/(.*)/(.*)$ /delete.aspx?page=$2&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/hcp/(.*)$ /delete.aspx?page=$1&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/hcp/([a-z]|[-])/([a-z]|[-])$ /delete.aspx?page=$2&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/hcp/([a-z]|[-])$ /delete.aspx?page=$1&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
```

and just for good measure ive just tried this

```
RewriteRule ^/hcp/(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /delete.aspx?page=$2&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/hcp/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /delete.aspx?page=$1&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
```

im trying to get it match either

```
www.site.com/hcp/parameter
```

and

```
www.site.com/hcp/param1/param2
```

for some reason it keeps putting everything into $1 and nothing into $2 or in the case of the second line the second $1 is blank for example

```
root = page = param1/param2
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/hcp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /delete.aspx?page=$2&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
RewriteRule ^/hcp/([^/]+)$ /delete.aspx?page=$1&root=$1 [NC,L,I]
```

Do you need to use the `B` flag too? I don't know how similar that rewriting is to Apache's.

Comment: brilliant thanks works great this also works RewriteRule ^/hcp/(.*)/(.*)$ /delete.aspx\?root=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]